# How does the firebase AuthStateListener work?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an android app using firebase for user management and authentication. I was wondering when the auth state listener gets called and how it works, as in my app I have a bug related to this.

Here is an example of one in my android app:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // Sign in logic here.
                }
            }
        };
```

How does the `AuthStateListener` work and when does it get called?

Comment: You didn't explained your bug

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the Firebase [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener#public-methods) says:

**`AuthStateListener`** is called when there is a change in the authentication state.

**`OnAuthStateChanged`** gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state:

- Right after the listener has been registered
- When a user is signed in
- When the current user is signed out
- When the current user changes
- <s>When there is a change in the current user's token</s> (Notice this has been **removed** and moved to a separate listener, see [FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener))

Comment: Thank you this really helped me understand! =)

Comment: And how does we suppose to know what happen? on each call? The FirebaseAuth instance didn't tell anything except for currentUser (only whether it exist or null).

Comment: Registering means addAuthStateListener(...) ?

Comment: [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) does not mention the 5th element listed in the answer ("When there is a change in the current user's token").

Comment: In response to payne, the 5th item has been removed and and moved to a separate listener [`FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener) (which still includes the rest of the items). @Ami, would suggest to edit it in your answer? Cheers!