# Firebase PhoneAuth.How to login with password

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently implemented phone auth in my app. But the issue is I can only create an account with it. I can't log back in.Using email auth we can login using our email and password.
here's my code:

```
public class PhoneReg extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editTextPhone, editTextCode;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    String codeSent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_reg);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        editTextCode = findViewById(R.id.otp);
        editTextPhone = findViewById(R.id.getPhoneNo);

        findViewById(R.id.getCodebtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendVerificationCode();
            }
        });


        findViewById(R.id.registerrr).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                verifySignInCode();
            }
        });
    }
    private void verifySignInCode(){
        String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeSent, code);
       signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {



        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Intent setupIntent=new Intent(PhoneReg.this,SetupActivity.class);
                            startActivity(setupIntent);
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Incorrect Verification Code ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(){

        String phone = editTextPhone.getText().toString();

        if(phone.isEmpty()){
            editTextPhone.setError("Phone number is required");
            editTextPhone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(phone.length() < 10 ){
            editTextPhone.setError("Please enter a valid phone");
            editTextPhone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }


        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phone,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    }



    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            codeSent = s;
        }
    };
}
```

I am able to register my user with phone Auth. But after I log out, I don't have an option to login in with any fields.

I have looked up at different places for an answer, I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase phone number authentication sends a text message to the phone number with a link. When the user opens that link, Firebase knows that they received the text messages, and signs them in.

On most cases you should leave the user signed in. When they restart the application, Firebase will restore their authentication state, and you can detect the user with [`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) or an [`AuthStateListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228376/how-does-the-firebase-authstatelistener-work).

If the user is signed out (usually because you explicitly sign them out), you can sign them in again by re-authenticating. So by resending a text message as shown in the [documentation on phone number authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth). Firebase will detect that this is the same user, and sign them in to the existing user account.

---

Signing in with email+password is a separate provider for Firebase Authentication. If you only enable phone number sign-in, the user can't automatically sign in with a password.

If you **also** want to allow the user to sign in with a password, you'll have to also integrate [email+password authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) into your app. You then [link the authentication providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) together, so that the user can sign in to their account with either of them,