# Getting error in when obtaining user.getUid()

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

i am using Fragment in android to share data.In the Main Activity i check if the current is null or not. In the Fragment's i don't check, because i already checked i MainActivity. But when i try to start the app, it's giving me error.

> Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Here i check if the user is null or not

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(
                                    Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
                                    )
                            )
                            .build(),
                    0);
        }
    }
```

and this is my Fragment

```
  DatabaseReference users = base.child("users");
            DatabaseReference uid = users.child(auth.getUid());
            DatabaseReference incidencies = uid.child("incidencies");



                FirebaseListOptions<Incidencia>  options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Incidencia>()
                        .setQuery(incidencies, Incidencia.class)
                        .setLayout(R.layout.layout_incidencia)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner())
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

`auth.getUid()` is returning null because no user is signed in at the time you're calling it, and you can't pass `null` to `child()`.  You should only call it when a user is signed in, or at least check it for null to do something different.  It doesn't necessarily matter if you previously checked for null - the sign in state can change over time.  Use an auth state listener to know when the sign in state changes.

- [How does the firebase AuthStateListener work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228376/how-does-the-firebase-authstatelistener-work)