# why my currentUser is always null if I login using facebook in firebase authentication?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

in login page, I use these 2 codes below:

```
    facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener {
          facebookLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"))
    }

    private fun setUpFacebookLogin() {

        facebookLoginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {

            override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:$loginResult")
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken)
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel")
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE

            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error)
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                mActivity.longToast("Gagal masuk dengan akun Facebook, silahkan periksa koneksi internet Anda, atau gunakan akun Google atau email yang lain.")

            }
        })

    }

    private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {

        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:$token")

        val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)

        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener {

            Log.d(TAG, "facebook signInWithCredential:success")

            val user = auth.currentUser ?: return@addOnSuccessListener
            checkUserBasicDataInFirestore(user)

        }.addOnFailureListener {exception ->

            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook signInWithCredential failed: ${exception.localizedMessage}")
            mActivity.longToast(exception.localizedMessage)
        }


    }
```

I actually can register the user to firebase auth by using those code, but I have problem when trying to login using facebook. `auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener` is triggered actually, so I assume I can success login using facebook in login page

but in the other screen (fragment), when I want to access the current user to get the uid, it always null, like this

```
val userFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
```

I don't understand why `userFirebaseAuth` is always null ?

Comment: Do you happen to be killing the app, then restarting it when you see null like this (or just launching it cold)?  Or are you signing in successfully, then trying immediately after that to get the current user?

Comment: @DougStevenson  after killing the app and restarting it like this (install again from Android Studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, the current user isn't always *immediately* available at the app launches from a cold start.  It can take a moment for Firebase Authentication to initialize and refresh the user's ID token if necessary.  Since you don't know how long that will take, you should use a listener to determine the first possible moment when the current user is absolutely known and verified by the SDK.  It's a good idea to read about: [How does the firebase AuthStateListener work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228376/how-does-the-firebase-authstatelistener-work)

Create a new AuthStateListener:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // Sign in logic here.
            }
        }
    };
```

Then add and remove it as needed:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
```

Also check out the [API documentation on AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener).

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue so posting this here in case it is helpful to someone else. Even though the user was already logged in through facebook login, `Firebase.auth.currentUser` was always null for me. I realized that I was accidentally using facebook login by itself rather than through firebase. I was able to get the correct login state of facebook by doing this:

```
val accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
val isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired
```

The way you would notify firebase about your facebook login after successfully signing in through facebook is the following. (Copied ofhttps://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase)

```
private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:$token")

    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
}
```

After doing this, Firebase.auth.currentUser will be populated!